# Proof for Neukirch mysterious relationship between frobenius elements in abstract CFT

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

In Neukirch's ANT chapter (4) on Abstract Class Field Theory, there is a claim which I can prove, but I can't prove the "In particular" part that follows. I'm stuck in this for almost a week. I've tried drawing some crazy diagrams, but I feel like this is a typo because I couldn't chase the diagram to conclude this.
[image]

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm confused - isn't this exactly what the diagram is saying? If not - what is $\phi$?

Comment: Thanks for commenting. Im also confused but I think I already figured it out by drawing a big diagram. It takes some time to explain all the notation used in this abstract version of CFT. $\varphi_{K}$ means Frobenius of K. Are you familiar with this book?

Comment: $\varphi_{L}$ is an element of a quotient of $G_{L}$ for example; so I need to be careful